# Why is the free energy unitless when taking the thermodynamic limit?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

Why is the (Helmhotz) free energy unitless when taking the thermodynamic limit? Given the partition function $Z$ of a (finite size) system, the free energy is given by
$F =-kT \log[Z]$,  where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant. (for example the Ising model with $N$  particles).

But when we take the thermodynamic limit, it becomes
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} -\frac{1}{N} \log[Z_N],$$
with $N$ the amount of particles.

I understand why you'd divide by $N$, but I don't understand why $kT$ is suddenly gone.

Comment: The unit of a physical quantity is determined with its definition and can't change afterwards. It's probably a typo in the document.

Comment: It's in multiple sources actually

Comment: My guess is that it's omitted for simplicity since we're usually interested in the critical points.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Working with dimensionless quantities is common and useful, so the quantity in your question could be $F/kT$.

Comment: There are often multiple conventions and definitions for a quantity, that may not be compatible between sources. You have to understand how your source defines the quantity; there is no universal "correct" answer. Clearly the two definitions you give are not compatible (although they may be closely related, as @Miyase points out). It would help a lot for you to provide context by giving an example of a source that uses the first definition, and a source that uses the second; then it might be possible for someone to explain how and why the two sources are using different definitions.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot take the thermodynamic limit on the extensive free energy $F$. It would result in a useless infinity!

In order to get a finite limit for the usual extensive thermodynamic systems, we must divide the free energy (and then the logarithm of the partition function) by another extensive quantity. In the canonical ensemble, we can choose either $V$ or $N$. Quite often, people work with dimensionless free energy, by dividing it by $kT$, in order to concentrate their attention on the quantities the limit depends on.